# Jquery Ajax and Spinner

Tags: json, api, jquery, tumblr

At [this demo site](http://essentiatheme.tumblr.com/), I'm sorting the posts using ajax and the Tumblr API. Everything works perfectly, with efficient error handling but seeing as I'm very new to jQuery I was wondering how/where/what I should do to show a spinner while the content is being loaded?

Here's the code I'm using to load the posts:

```
function byCategory(postType, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: '{URL}/api/read/json?type=' + postType + 
      '&callback=?',
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(results){
        console.info("Success!");
        yourCallbackToRunIfSuccessful(results);
     },

 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
     console.info("Error, the Tumblr API is down and cannot serve your request");
     yourErrorHandler(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
     }
    });
```

Any help from the ninja's out there will be *greatly* appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `$('#spinner').show()` on button click or submit when you trigger the function (just put it after the start of the function, above the ajax call)

In the success, simply do a `$('#spinner').hide();`

Comment: Awesome - I get to learn something new every day. Thanks loads bpeterson :)